# Row colour gaps in tabularx with \aboverulesep and \{}

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, rowcolor

[image: table color]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol,booktabs,tabularx}

% Table settings
\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{1pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X l@{}}
        This is Header 1 & This is Header 2 \\
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{Apricot}
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I have the above table MWE using `tabularx`, and I am trying to colour the row from the table. However, due to the use of my `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`, I now have gaps above and below my table row that is not coloured.

Also, because of the use of my `@{}` on either side of the table to 'remove' the excess padding on the sides of the table, the row colour is being applied in those padding as well.

**Qn 1:** How can I colour the aforementioned gaps (arising due to the `\aboverulesep`) in, while maintaining the rule separation?

**Qn 2:** How to remove the colour from the two sides of the table?

---

### EDIT

This is in response to Zarko's answer. I want to maintain the use of `@{}` on either side to remove the padding. If I were to adapt this into your answer, like so:

```
% @Zarko's answer
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, tabularx}

% Table settings
\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}SX Sl@{}}% <-- S is append for activate additional vertical space 
        This is Header 1 & This is Header 2 \\
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{Apricot}
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I obtain this: [image]

and so my second question (**Qn2**) is still unresolved.. For Qn 1, I prefer to use the solution by @Skillmon with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}` as I need not add a new package.

Comment: You might set the `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` to `0pt` and use `\setstretch` from the `setspace`-package. Then the entire line is coloured. (approx. `\setstretch{1.15}` seems to fit your ruleseps)

Comment: @Skillmon Yup that works nicely for the first question. Thank you.

Comment: Just make sure, you use the `\setstretch` inside of a group and the group is it's own paragraph, so that `\setstretch` doesn't affect other text.

Comment: Just realized, you might use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}` instead of `\setstretch`. It results in the same, but is not dependand on `setspace`.

Comment: @Skillmon Indeed so! In this case, it's alright that I leave this in my preamble? i.e. it only affects my tables, not my main text body?

Comment: Sorry for being late. It affects everything which uses the `\arraystretch` internally (e.g., `array`-environment), but should not affect your normal text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of possibilities is to use `cellspace` package:

[image]

First the vertical space around `booktabs` rules i reduced to zero pt, than is increased by macro `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` to desired vertical (colored) gap:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, tabularx}

% Table settings
\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{SX Sl}% <-- S is append for activate additional vertical space 
        This is Header 1 & This is Header 2 \\
        \toprule
    \rowcolor{Apricot}
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
works around to second part of question. It need to introduce fake column (or to have zero distance between columns or white space with width of two `\tabcolsep`):

[image]

This time without additional package but with tricks how to use `\rowcolor` (for details see documentation for package `colortbl`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

% Table settings
\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X c<{\hspace{12pt}} l }
        This is Header 1 && This is Header 2 \\
        \toprule
    \rowcolor{Apricot}%[0pt]
        This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is && This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 && This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 && This is Text 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (2):**
After four years ... Now I would use new table package `tabularray`. Using it for the MWE in above addendum is code simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[1,l]  l @{}},
                 column{1} = {rightsep=12pt},
                 row{2} = {bg=Apricot},
                 }
This is Header 1 &  This is Header 2    \\
    \toprule
This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1
                & This is Text 2        \\
    \midrule 
This is Text 1  & This is Text 2        \\
    \midrule
This is Text 1  & This is Text 2        \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to maintain the use of `@{}`, that is, I don't want the padding on either side of the table. Notice that in your example now, there is spurious spacing beside all the `This...` and `...2`'s

Comment: @ksgj1, you can return @{}, but it cause ... you will see what. If you like to have such table, than is ok. but people in the most cases don't want this, they say, discrapancy :)

Comment: Hi Zarko, I shown my output above. I would like to have such a table, indeed. But I hope you understand that was part of my second question, so I would still hope to get an answer for that. That is, use the `@{}` and *not* have the row colour extend out of the table..

Comment: @ksgj1, see addendum to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for pointing me to the `colortbl` package! I tried to dissect your code, figure out why it's working etc. The `[0pt]` argument on the row colour is unnecessary, yes? Since the `tabcolsep` has already been set to `0pt`. :p Anyway, I have a small gripe about your answer (please, as *constructive* criticism), which is that I have to manually edit in additional alignment points in my tables. (I have quite a few of these tables, so I would like to minimize my work :))

Comment: Anyway, I will post my alternate solution (inspired by yours!) also, which is the one I'll be using, since there's no need to add the additional column. But the credit still goes to you, for the time you've spent on this. Thanks!

Comment: regarding`[0pt]`, it was left from experiments to use `@{}` on the beginning and end of table columns definition. since I on the end set `tabcolsep` to zero, it becomes surplus (i correct answer). for fake column, as I said in answer, if you not need the `\tabcolsep` space between columns, this columns is also surplus. I strongly encourage you to wrote own answer! Learning-by-doing is the mots effective way to learn! I successful test this almost each day :)

Comment: I just successfully converted my tabu tables to tabularray. It's a lot simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution by OP

This is an alternative solution to @Zarko's solution with regards to my second question, on how to remove the spurious colours on either side of the table when using `\rowcolor{}`, while still keeping the use of `@{}`, in a `tabularx`environment. This has the additional benefit (compared to Zarko's answer) of not requiring to add a separate column in the middle and having to add additional alignment points throughout all the rows.

In the answer below, I have also incorporated @Skillmon's suggestion of using `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}` with regards to my first question.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

% Table settings
\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}X >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}l @{}}
        This is Header 1 & This is Header 2 \\
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{Apricot}
        This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1  & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

---

---

### Explanation of code

The main approach was to exploit the use of overhangs by the `\columncolor` command from the `colortbl` package, also called by the `xcolor` package with the `table` optional argument.

Note that the `\columncolor` command takes in optional arguments as such:

```
\columncolor{colour} [left overhang][right overhang]
```

So I just set the left overhang of the leftmost column to be 0pt, thereby getting rid of the spurious space on the left throughout the column, and right overhang to be `\tabcolsep` which is basically a distance separating the columns. I did the same for the right overhang of the rightmost column, set it to be 0pt, while setting its left overhang to `\tabcolsep`. This essentially **fixes** the column widths, as I want.

Obviously the colour of both columns in `\columncolor` have to be set to `white`, and one final thing to note is that when `\rowcolor` is called later in the table, it will **override** this `white` colour of the `\columncolor`, thereby still giving us the benefit of having the row colour set correctly.

Read the `colortbl` package manual [here](http://mirror.pregi.net/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf).

Comment: excellent answer! good trick with `columncolor`!

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{}Xl@{}}[colortbl-like]
        This is Header 1 & This is Header 2 \\
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{Apricot}
        This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1 This is Text 1  & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\\midrule
        This is Text 1 & This is Text 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]