# tabularx and colortbl: Cell Color When Using @{} and Cell Height When Using German Umlaut (e. g. Ü)

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, colortbl

- I am trying to make a template for gym workouts (a table that fills a whole page, see [here](http://www.nackt-besser-aussehen.info) if you are interested, German website).
- **Problem one** is that the German umlauts (e. g. Ü) have too little space to the cell border.
- **Problem two** is that the cell color is leaving the cell when the I use `@{}` in the column definition.
- Apparently, I used the wrong search terms -- I could have bet that I am not the first person that encounters these problems.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

% For "Umlauts"
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    margin = 5mm,
    landscape,
    %showframe,
    ]
    {geometry}

% Table stuff
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Loads also "colortbl"
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    

% Nice sans serif font :)
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l|l|X|X@{}}
\hline
Übung & Parameter & \\
\hline
\cellcolor{blue!25} Color Cell & \cellcolor{blue!25} Color Cell  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Keine Ursache ;-)

Comment: for second question see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365685/row-colour-gaps-in-tabularx-with-aboverulesep-and/365698#365698, for the first: try to add `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`

Comment: Off-topic: Don't insert any whitespace between `cellcolor{<some color>}` and the cell's contents. Your screenshot shows the result of not adhering to this recommendation...

Comment: @Mico *Thanks*. I didn't see any problem so far but I also didn't focus on that.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. Still confused that the 1st question is not more popular on the internet :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - For your first question, you should check out [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5001) to the query [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5001).

Comment: I wonder now, why I write only the comment  (which solve OP problems) and not the answer ...

Comment: @Zarko Please add an answer...I also was wondering.

Comment: Now it can only be the same as of *Bernard* /this you can see from my comment/... and I notice his answer few minutes ago (to be honest, during writing of comment my wife spur /drängen/ me to our dinner :(, so had to left PC immediately  :) ) . My bed.

Comment: @Zarko "Luckily" I am alone at home :). Thanks for the help! I upvoted another answer of you to make it right :).

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the optional arguments of `\colorcolumn`. For the umlauts problem, a simple `\extrarowheight` will do. I took the liberty of changing the input encoding to `utf8`, which is understood by all OSes and modern editors.

```
\documentclass{article}

% For "Umlauts"
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    margin = 5mm,
    landscape,
    %showframe,
    ]
    {geometry}

% Table stuff
\usepackage{tabularx}


% Loads also "colortbl"
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Nice sans serif font :)
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}

\noindent\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{blue!25}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l|>{\columncolor{blue!25}}l|X|X@{}}
\hline
\rowcolor{white}Übung & Parameter & \\
\hline
Color Cell & Color Cell & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for changing the `inputenc` option to `utf8`. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I wasn't clear in my example. I want to change the row color manually for some rows. In your code I need to change it to white in many rows ;).

Comment: @Mico I still like to use `latin1`:).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - If you've set up your editor to use `latin1` as the input encoding system, you automatically make your code unusable and unsuitable for processing by XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Even if you don't anticipate having to use either of these two LaTeX formats for the foreseeable future, why would you deliberately create an incompatibility that will be quite tedious to undo if and when you decide to switch to a more modern LaTeX format? Put differently, why do you *not* wish to use `utf8` input encoding?

Comment: I  tried first using the optional arguments for row colours, but this leaves white spaces in the internal cells, due to this dissymmetry in `\tabcolsep`, so I don't see a way to obtain what you want at the row level.

Comment: @Mico I wasn't serious -- you are right, of course. It's just a habit.