# Getting gray column in a table

Tags: tables

I have a table where a column with gray background is used. The table has subdivisions: Sub and Type. The gray column (central Total column in the attached code) has white lines/spaces where the subdivision lines are present, between Sub and Type. Can these white lines/spaces removed.

Also there appears a small white patch below the last gray row how can that be removed.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr>{\bfseries}grrrrr}\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\emph{Sub}} & &
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{\emph{ Type}}   \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-9} 
\textbf{C} & sc & ss & ma & Total& L & B & P & O \\ \midrule
5&  0&  1&  5&  6&  1&  3&  2&  0\\ 
6&  0&  1&  42& 43& 23& 9&  1&  10\\
7&  8&  4&  19& 31& 19& 9&  1&  2\\ 
8&  3&  3&  39& 45& 22& 11& 11& 1\\
9&  14& 11& 41& 66& 47& 9&  4&  6\\ 
10& 4&  21& 35& 60& 23& 8&  13& 16\\
\hline \rowcolor{Gray}
\textbf{Total} & 29 & 41 & 181 & \textbf{251}& 135& 49& 32&  35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `booktabs` and `colortbl` (or `[table]{xcolor}` doesn't like each other very much ... see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365685/ if this can help you.

Comment: I had the same problem. Booktabs and color are not friends. Search for "Booktabs colortbl". And maybe reduce the complexity of the example.

Comment: @zarko same thought :)

Comment: Thanks @zarko the link that you have provided has answer that works like a charm.