# >{\kern-\tabcolsep} does not work in p-columns

Tags: tables, kerning, rowcolor

If you colourise a row in a table, `@{}` does not remove the colour from the side bearings, as demonstrated in below figure.

[image]

To remove the colour, you may direct a kern into the table column using `>{\kern-\tabcolsep}`, as demonstrated in below figure:

[image]

However, this does not work if the column you want to kern is a `p`-column. Instead, the cell content no longer lines up with the next cell, as demonstrated below:

[image]

Why? Is it possible to use `\kern` in some way (I know setting `\tabcolsep` to zero may have the same effect, but doing that has some side effects)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern, microtype, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lcr@{}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\\hline
test&test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\

\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}lcr<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\\hline
test&test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}p{1cm}cr<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\\hline
test&test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See addendum in answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365685/row-colour-gaps-in-tabularx-with-aboverulesep-and if it ca help you.

Comment: Using columncolor with the left and right overhang options mght also be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis You may easily(?) circumvent this effect by setting `tabcolsep` to zero and use narrow, empty columns to set space between the columns. However, I wonder if it is possible to use the `\kern` trick in some way.

Comment: @Zarko I know it is possible to circumvent the problem by using tabcolsep. But if you have 15 columns with content, you need additional 14 narrow columns to simulate tabcolsep.

Comment: You added a vertical kern not a horizontal one

Comment: Yes or use the latex syntax `\hspace"`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: @Sveinung: No, not really, what I actually referred to is the following solution/trick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365742/134144 where 
ksgj1 used `>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}` before the first and `>{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}` before the last column and later on colored the row with the usual `\rowcolor` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixed width columns, you may add `\leavevmode` or use `\hskip`:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern, microtype, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lcr@{}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\\hline
test&test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\

\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}lcr<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\\hline
test&test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{>{\leavevmode\kern-\tabcolsep}p{1cm}cr<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\\hline
test&test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{>{\hskip-\tabcolsep}p{1cm}cr<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\\hline
test&test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}test&test&test\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added*: In case you have a fixed width column, if a cell has several lines, only the first line has a negative kerning. A workaround consist in including the cell contents in a `\parbox[t]{\hsize}` (the optional`[t]` was suggested by @Sveinung – thanks!). This works also for the `X` column type if you use a `tabularx` environment.

For the `L, R, C, J` column types from `tabulary`, it seems you also have to add `\leavevmode` (or use `\hskip`)  for the last column, even if it is not a fixed width column.

Comment: Give a small moment to test.

Comment: It works width tabulary and tabularx. I realised that this was easy to test for myself, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, `\leavevmode` only kerns the first line if the cell content occupies more than one line. The same for `\hspace{0pt}`!

Comment: It doesn't work so well indeed: if the cell is multilined, you have to put it in a `\parbox{\hsize}`. As to `tabulary`, the right-hand column, even if it has not a fixed width, also requires `\leavevmode` or `\hskip` (not perfect, though).

Comment: The `\parbox{\hsize}{<cell content>} did the trick, but I had to add the optional alignment command (`[t]` in my case), because `\parbox` influences spacing in the next column (a top aligned parbox with list environment and no spacing at top)

Comment: Please, add these tips to you answer. I will wait a day before accepting, to see if other solutions materialise.

Comment: I've added some explanations Do you think it's clear enough?

Comment: Thank you Bernard! David Carlisle confirmed that `\leavevmode` or `\hspace` is the correct remedy, so I have accepted your answer.