# Is it possible to redirect unbalanced braces (`{` and `}`) into a tabular column?

Tags: tables, braces, parbox

This question is a follow up to my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504669/9632):

Is it possible to use `>` and `<` to pipe opening and closing braces on each side of a cell's content? To be more specific, what I want is to define the following column:

```
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\leavevmode\kern-\tabcolsep\bfseries\parbox[t]{\hsize}{}X<{}}}
```

I want a column type that automatically embraces the cell content in a `\parbox`.

I enclose a short MNWE:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern, microtype, xcolor, tabularx, tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.5\columnwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\leavevmode\kern-\tabcolsep\parbox[t]{\hsize}{ }X<{}}XX<{\leavevmode\kern-\tabcolsep\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}All this testing is not so funny&test&test\\\hline
testing, testing and even more testing &test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}I want to write a noce table in a simple way&test&test\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `X` column type is based on ˙\parbox`es. Why you like to add them again? If you have some reason to do this, it might be better to use `\minipage` (on left side)  `\endminipge` (on the right side of column type)

Comment: In case you really have to split unbalanced braces across the format specifiers, the different [brace tricks from The TeXbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10371/23765) apply

Comment: @Zarko Because I want to kern all the line in the cell and then I have to embrace the content in a `parbox` (see Bernard's answer to the referred question). `minipage` add top spacing, which then needs to be cancelled and complicated the column definition even more. After posting the question, I remembered the package [collcell](https://ctan.org/pkg/collcell), which probably will do want I want.

Comment: @siracusa Thank you for making me aware of this. I search extensively on SE, but this question did not show up. Unfortunately, this seems to be above my competence, but I will study it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spanning the braces over `>{}` and `<{}` seems harder than expected; I can't come up with a way that uses explicit brace tokens. Here is an alternative solution that uses TeX's delimited arguments. Instead of using the `\parbox` directly, we define a helper macro `\parboxx ... \endparboxx` that wraps it. This macro is then used in the new column type `P`:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern, microtype, xcolor, tabularx, tabulary}

\begin{document}

\def\parboxx#1\endparboxx{\parbox[t]{\hsize}{\raggedright#1}}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\leavevmode\kern-\tabcolsep\bfseries\parboxx}X<{\endparboxx}}

\begin{tabularx}{0.5\columnwidth}{PXX<{\leavevmode\kern-\tabcolsep\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}

\rowcolor{lightgray}All this testing is not so funny&test&test\\\hline
testing, testing and even more testing &test&test\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}I want to write a noce table in a simple way&test&test\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be a possible solution.